# Google Map inside Datatables not working

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin. i have link to Google map on each row, on click it will popup. Before using data-tables plugin, its was popping up, now click on it going to Google maps straight away.

I tried doing same out of the table, its working fine, but inside the table is not working. i had same issue with color-box also, for that i included the script in "fnInitComplete", then it worked. so how can i get the map working in popup.

Comment: code or it didn't happen.